# Compress & Optimise Existing Images

Tags: joomla-3.x, images, server, compression

Joomla 3.9.21

I am working on a site that is very image heavy, most images are within the EasyBlog component and amount to approximately 8GB, the original administrators didn't optimise the images for web when uploading them.

I need to compress these images somehow so that they aren't taking up so much resources on the server, however I don't want to affect their dimensions or picture quality.

Rather than download all the images manually and bath process them in Photoshop and re-uplad I was looking for some ideas?

I know that Easyblog offer an [image optimisation service](https://stackideas.com/dashboard/optimizer) but i'm wondering if I can somehow implement a similar reduction for free?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a NodeJS approach because...why not, eh?

#### Step 1

Download all images and put them in a folder.

#### Step 2

Open your terminal (cmd, GitBash, etc) and navigate to your folder:

```
cd /path/my-folder
```

#### Step 3

Inside the folder, create a JS file (e.g `compress.js`) and add the following code:

```
const imagemin = require('imagemin')
const imageminWebp = require('imagemin-webp')
 
(async () => {
    await imagemin(['*.{jpg,png}'], 'compressed/images', {
        use: [
            imageminWebp({quality: 100})
        ]
    });
 
    console.log('Complete!')
})();
```

#### Step 4

Run the JS file

```
node compress.js
```

#### Step 5

Run the following

```
npm install imagemin imagemin-webp
```

Comment: This looks great @Lodder thanks - what sort of reduction would you expect from this?

Comment: Well this converts the images to `webp`, which is a "next-gen" format, so you'll see quite a reduction. I'd suggest converting 1-2 images and adjusting the quality parameter, so you can guage the minimum. Please note I haven't tested this yet, so let me know if you run into any errors